# Remove list values when it contains specific characters from other list python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hi I have a dict named 'd' and a list ' to_be_removed' where the values in the list are as follows:

```
d:

{'data': [' VL0002511CA       000000000682414100000000000110000        ',
 ' VL0002511ZZ       000000000682414100000000000110000        ',
 ' VL0002512  PRE1985000000000682414100000000000110000        ',
 ' VL0002521CA       000000001888990100000000000310000        ',
 ' VL0002521ZZ       000000001888990100000000000310000        ',
 ' VL0002522  PRE1985000000001888990100000000000310000        ',
 ' VL0002531CA       000000001223831100000000000210000        ',
 ' VL0002531ZZ       000000001223831100000000000210000        ',
 ' VL0002532  PRE1985000000001223831100000000000210000        ',
 ' VL0007871CA       000000001463787100000000000210000        ',
 ' VL0007871ZZ       000000001463787100000000000210000        ']}

to_be_removed:
Out[14]:

['ZZ', 'PRE']
```

I need to remove those list values which contains the string 'ZZ' and 'PRE' from the list d. So my output list should be only values:

```
final_list:
{'data': [' VL0002511CA       000000000682414100000000000110000        ',
 ' VL0002521CA       000000001888990100000000000310000        ',
 ' VL0002531CA       000000001223831100000000000210000        ',
 ' VL0007871CA       000000001463787100000000000210000        ']}
```

How can I do this in python?

Comment: You can use regular expressions. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html>

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comprehension as follows:

```
d = {'data': [' VL0002511CA       000000000682414100000000000110000        ',
 ' VL0002511ZZ       000000000682414100000000000110000        ',
 ' VL0002512  PRE1985000000000682414100000000000110000        ',
 ' VL0002521CA       000000001888990100000000000310000        ',
 ' VL0002521ZZ       000000001888990100000000000310000        ',
 ' VL0002522  PRE1985000000001888990100000000000310000        ',
 ' VL0002531CA       000000001223831100000000000210000        ',
 ' VL0002531ZZ       000000001223831100000000000210000        ',
 ' VL0002532  PRE1985000000001223831100000000000210000        ',
 ' VL0007871CA       000000001463787100000000000210000        ',
 ' VL0007871ZZ       000000001463787100000000000210000        ']}

to_be_removed = ['PRE', 'ZZ']
updated = {'data': [item for item in d['data'] if not any(subst in item for subst in to_be_removed)] }
print(updated)
```

**Output**

```
{'data': [' VL0002511CA       000000000682414100000000000110000        ', 
' VL0002521CA       000000001888990100000000000310000        ', 
' VL0002531CA       000000001223831100000000000210000        ', 
' VL0007871CA       000000001463787100000000000210000        ']}
```

To allow for dictionaries with multiple keys, use a dict comprehension:

```
updated = {k: [item for item in v if not any(subst in item for subst in to_be_removed)] for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `[]` in the `any` argument.

Comment: Also, you can make it a dict comprehension so it also works with dictionaries with more than one element. Apart from that, exactly what I just wanted to post.

Comment: Yes, I was also fiddling with a dict comprehension but thought it was beginning to look too messy! Think I will take another look now

Answer (score 0):

You can use [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function and list generation/comprehension.

```
d={'data': [' VL0002511CA       000000000682414100000000000110000        ',
          ' VL0002511ZZ       000000000682414100000000000110000        ',
          ' VL0002512  PRE1985000000000682414100000000000110000        ',
          ' VL0002521CA       000000001888990100000000000310000        ',
          ' VL0002521ZZ       000000001888990100000000000310000        ',
          ' VL0002522  PRE1985000000001888990100000000000310000        ',
          ' VL0002531CA       000000001223831100000000000210000        ',
          ' VL0002531ZZ       000000001223831100000000000210000        ',
          ' VL0002532  PRE1985000000001223831100000000000210000        ',
          ' VL0007871CA       000000001463787100000000000210000        ',
          ' VL0007871ZZ       000000001463787100000000000210000        ']}

to_be_removed=['ZZ', 'PRE']
lst = []
for j in d['data']:
    if all(not i in j for i in to_be_removed):
        lst.append(j)

final_data = {'data': lst}
print final_data
```

**Or just a one liner**-

```
print {'data': [j for j in d['data'] if all(not i in j for i in to_be_removed)]}
```

Output-

```
{'data': [' VL0002511CA       000000000682414100000000000110000        ', ' VL0002521CA       000000001888990100000000000310000        ', ' VL0002531CA       000000001223831100000000000210000        ', ' VL0007871CA       000000001463787100000000000210000        ']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with `re.sub`, `list comprehension` and `dict comprehension`:

```
In [182]: {'data' : [l2 for l2 in [re.sub('.*[(ZZ)|(PRE)]+.*', '', l1) for l1 in d['data']] if l2]}
Out[182]:
{'data': [' VL0002511CA       000000000682414100000000000110000        ',
  ' VL0002521CA       000000001888990100000000000310000        ',
  ' VL0002531CA       000000001223831100000000000210000        ',
  ' VL0007871CA       000000001463787100000000000210000        ']}
```